# Merging 2 SharePoint Sites

Tags: 2010, 2007, sharepoint-designer

I am merging 2 Sharepoint site owned by different people , one in SP 2007 and one on SP 2010.

What questions should I be asking to scope amount of work required ?

I was thinking about determine content on sites 1st ( doc libraries, Sharepoint lists) and then a general chat about users etc.

Comment: Where are you merging these sites to? My assumption is into the 2010 site (or another site in the 2010 farm) since you can't go the other way.

Comment: Business request . Just need to understand what questions to ask ..